# openwrt source code edit

Tags: openwrt

I am building my own handshake replacing WPA. I want to do this for a school project and implement my own security algorithm. I will achieve this by editing the source code of OPENWRT at last. Can anybody help me [in this code](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/) where I can edit the beacon frames that the router send and also regarding wpa security handshake until a connection is made. (dont worry I will use a similar keystream to wpa just a different handshake that implements it) So I need to know which files I should edit the source code of to edit beacons/ beacon intervals and the first wpa 4 way handshake (or whether unprotected)

Comment: This should not have been migrated to Stack Overflow in its current form. We require questions to contain the problematic code _in the question itself,_ in a small and self-contained example which illustrates where exactly you are stuck and what you have done to resolve the problem yourself. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].